# How to set up CWAC-Provider to be accessible from another app?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, commonsware-cwac, android-fileprovider

I'm relatively new to ContentProviders in Android and I liked the idea of sharing asset files between apps.
Let's say I have 2 apps: AppA has all the nice images I want to access from AppB. AppA has StreamProvider set like this:

```
<provider
        android:authorities="org.example.AssetProvider"
        android:name="com.commonsware.cwac.provider.StreamProvider"
        android:exported="true"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.commonsware.cwac.provider.STREAM_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/assetpaths" />
</provider>
```

with assetpaths.xml like this:

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <asset name="assets" path="test"/>
</paths>
```

All works well and I can access my assets through StreamProvider in my AppA (getUriPrefix() for that authority returns some non-null value).

The difficult part begins when I try to access the assets from my AppB with this code:

```
String COMMON_AUTHORITY = "org.example.AssetProvider";
Uri test = Uri.parse("content://" + COMMON_AUTHORITY)
    .buildUpon()
    .appendPath(StreamProvider.getUriPrefix(COMMON_AUTHORITY))
    .appendPath("assets")
    .appendPath("test.jpg")
    .build();
InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(test)
```

The getUriPrefix() method returns null as there is no Provider registered in INSTANCES private field of StreamProvider class. When I wrote down the prefix from running this code in AppA and then hard-coded it AppB, it all went well and I could obtain an InputStream.

My questions are -

1. Is there any way how I can access the prefix of my Authority from another app?
2. Is there any other way I can access files stored in another app's APK file?

Thank you for your reply in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AppA, [subclass `StreamProvider` and override `getUriPrefix()` to return `null`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider/blob/master/docs/EXTENDING.markdown#customizing-the-uri-prefix). Use the subclass in your `<provider>` element. Then, build the `Uri` in AppB without a prefix.

BTW, you should be able to remove `android:grantUriPermissions="true"`, as you are exporting this provider.